# Can you rename or name Reporting Services jobs?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

In Report Manager you can create schedules, either shared or one-of's.  When you create these schedules a job is created in SQL Server with names that look like guids.  IS it safe to rename these jobs to something readable and understandable, or will renaming them break something?  Or, is there to give these schedules a name in Report Mnager that will be reflected in the job?

Comment: The code that I posted earlier changes the name of the jobs in the ReportSchedule and the Schedule tables.  I had not been able to test it and should not have posted it. I will do so and then repost when I can give you expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUID identifies the job in the ReportServer database too. So don't change it.

That is, the schedule uses uniqueidentifier datatype in the table: the value matches the job